# Adding cssClasses to mermaid class diagram

Tags: mermaid

Trying to add a styleClass to nodes in my class diagram in mermaid using the explained syntax in the [docs](https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/classDiagram.html#classes)

```html
<style>
  .styleClass > rect {
    fill: #ff0000;
    stroke: #ffff00;
    stroke-width: 4px;
  }
</style>
```

```
classDiagram
    class Animal:::styleClass
```

I'm not sure where to define the css class (`<style>....</style>` part)

I'm using mermaid from the Visual Studio extension / the live editor.

tried to put it as part of the diagram and also as part of the %%init segment in the start of the diagram